# jQuery .empty() overwrites .appendTo()

Tags: jquery

I have an Image modal popup that is filled with a single image by a jQuery function.

This popup displays when you click on any thumbnail (I have a thumbnail image gallery) to enlarged the image. The enlarged image will popup in the modal.

Here is how I call it:

```
$('#articleFeatured').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#imageModal').show(500);
    $('#imageModal').empty(); //empty modal to prevent clogging/build-up/duplicates
    $('#articleFeatured img').clone().appendTo('#imageModal #imageHolder');
    //imageModal Close Button Functionality
    $('#close_button').click(function () {
        $('#imageModal').hide(500);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the

```
.empty()
```

overwrites the

```
.appendTo()
```

function.

Why is that? I mean the appendTo runs **after** the empty.
The reason why I use `.empty()` is to have one image in the modal at the time and prevents build-up.

Comment: `.appendTo('#imageModal #imageHolder')` means the element with id `imageHolder` inside the element with id `imageModal`. Since you just emptied the `imageModal` element, the selector never matches anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite" in this context?

Comment: By the way, unless in very specific cases, looking for an element by id inside an other element is wrong. `'#imageModal #imageHolder'` is very probably not the right selector.

Comment: @ dystroy - yeah that's true, never though about that...

Comment: Can we see your HTML so that we could actually _suggest_ a solution?

Comment: @dystroy You can sometimes see code like `#checkout-page #shopping-cart` in my CSS. I that wrong or very specific?

Comment: `#id #otherId` in CSS is useful only when the second element moves around and you want to style it differently depending on where it's placed.

Comment: @JanDvorak only if you want the selector to apply when the second element is inside the first one. That's one of those "very specific cases" and it has a performance penalty.

Comment: @dystroy how big of a performance penalty? Only if the element _is_ `#shopping-cart`, then the inheritance is actually checked.

Comment: Thank you Juhana - Did not pick that up. thank you. Please put it as an answer and i will give you the points

Comment: @JanDvorak The difference is too small to even measure, but why have it if it's unnecessary? It's like adding `if( true && 1 != 2 && ... )` to your conditionals.

Comment: @Juhana in my case, it's more of "select `#shopping-cart`, but only if we're on the `#checkout-page`". Very useful in global stylesheets (not the best design choice, I know)

Comment: @JanDvorak Well that's a legit use of double-ids and the most efficient one.

Comment: @Juhana - could you please add your commnet as an answer, so that i can close this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.appendTo('#imageModal #imageHolder')` to `.appendTo('#imageModal')`. The `imageModal` element has just been emptied so it can't contain an element with the id `imageHolder`.